# Regex cut the words out of the sentence C#

Tags: c#, html, regex, string, text

I have some sentences that I would like to extract some words by Regex in C#

Example like:

//**Standard room 1 persons** from 18/03/2014 to 19/03/2014

Get the "Standard room 1 persons" out of the sentence, remove from xxxx to xxxx

//**Family night room 3/4** from 18/03/2014 to 19/03/2014

Get the "Family night room" and 3/4 is the number of persons in the room and I would like to take the 4 out to be a maximum number of person in the room.

For both cases, the from and to are ignored.

Could you please suggest me the reg ex pattern to do those things ( 2 cases )?

Thank you very much and have a nice day!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: when saying 'cut out' you mean 'extract'?

Comment: `^(.*)(?=( from))` will fetch everthing before the 'from'. `(?<=\/)(\d)` will fetch the number after the '/'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use this:

```
string s = "//Standard room 1 and 1/4 persons from 18/03/2014 to 19/03/2014";
            string matchedStr = Regex.Match(s, ".*(?=from)(?=.*to)").Value;
            Console.WriteLine(matchedStr);
            string totalStr = Regex.Match(s, ".*(?=from)(?=.*to)").Value;
            int total=Convert.ToInt32(Regex.Match(totalStr,@"(?<=\d/)\d").Value);
            Console.WriteLine(total);
```

Comment: Thank you but the first example string s, it took the "from 18/03/2014 to 19/03/2014" instead of the "standard room 1 person", could you please have a check again, thank you very much.

Comment: I would like to take the Standard room 1 person out of the string, in your example, the regex cut the rest "from 18/03/2014 to 19/03/2014" not the "Standard room 1 person" Thank you @Amit Joki

Answer (score 0):

If you don't insist on Regex:

```
string[] array1 = "Standard room 1 persons from 18/03/2014 to 19/03/2014".Split();
string[] array2 = "Family night room 3/4 from 18/03/2014 to 19/03/2014".Split();

string n = String.Join(" ", array1.TakeWhile(s => s != "from").ToArray());
string n2 = String.Join(" ", array2.TakeWhile(s => s != "from").ToArray());

Console.WriteLine(n);  // Standard room 1 persons 
Console.WriteLine(n2); // Family night room 3/4
```

Comment: I thought 'cut out' means remove, but seems you are correct!!

Comment: @user2720372 : Thank you for your example! I could understand one more way to do without regex

Comment: OP is asking for `4` in `1/4`, `6` in `1/6`,but yours returns the full string

Answer (score 0):

Sample code:

```
string input = "Standard room 1 persons from 18/03/2014 to 19/03/2014"
string s = Regex.Match(input, "(.*)(?=from)").Value;
s = s.Trim();

// Get your maximum number
MatchCollection numbers = Regex.Matches(s, "[\d]");
int max = 0;
foreach (Match number in numbers)
{
     int temp = int.Parse(number.Value);
     if (max > temp)
        max = temp;
}
```

Comment: OP is also asking for total number of people also

Comment: that would match any digit 123, 55. OP is asking for 4 in 1/4, 6 in 1/6

Comment: `int.Parse(number)` should be `int.Parse(number.Value)`

Comment: I'll take my downvote for your efforts, while you still didn't get what OP had asked for ;)